# Modelling Login and Authentication on an iOS mobile client

Tags: design, ios, mobile, object, cocoa

I'm about to start working on a V2 of a mobile application and I'd like to adopt  a more object-centric approach.  Primarily because I think it makes for more maintainable code, but a secondary benefit is easier testability.

V1 of the app is pretty controller-centric.  The Login ViewController has its login fields and it hits the backend via AFNetworking, reports errors if necessary, and receives a token which gets stored away securely for later use.

There's only ever a single user.  When the user logs out, all local data is deleted, so essentially the current user is 'global' and can either be nil (need a login) or not (doesn't).

The situation is complicated of course by the idea of token expiry.  Essentially any network request (either explicit GETs or asynchronous, delayed POSTs) can fail because the token expired and we want the user to re-authenticate.

The V1 model of a login screen at startup if there's no current user doesn't easily extend to this model, and I feel,I'm missing an object somehow I'd route everything through.  An Authenticator that provides a token, or throws up the login screen if it doesn't have one.

Then we could do something like - when any request fails, we delete the current token and retry the request.  The request asks the authenticator for the token, and the authenticator asks the user.

Or something.

How this could be better modelled?

I feel like the code needs to be centralised, but that's hard as requests are used throughout the apps.  Its almost like a filter layer is needed to handle auth errors centrally, but other errors / successes wherever they're needed (in a success/fail block).

Comment: Frankly I don't see what exactly is the problem. The case when user isn't logged in or has no token are somewhat similar, and I don't see where is the difficulty of implementing both cases.

Comment: The user not being logged in is easy to determine at startup.  An expired token can happen for any request, whether user-initiated or not, at any point during the session.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem with a "controller centric" way.

Let's start with a Root View Controller, who owns a "User" object.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    if (self.user && self.user.isAuthenticated) {
        [self showSensitiveData];
    } else {
        [self getAuthenticatedUserWithModal];
    }
}
```

This is simple enough, but of course if the user becomes unauthenticated at any point, then your Root View Controller needs to know about it. I like to use Reactive Cocoa, but you could also do this with KVO or delegation:

```
- (void)authenitcationViewControllerDidFinishWithUser:(User *)user
{
    self.user = user;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)setUser:(User *)
{
    _user = user;
    if (user) {
        @weakify(self);
        [RACObserve(self.user.isAuthenticated) subscribeNext:(id) x ^{
            @strongify(self);
            if(!self.user.isAuthenticated) {
                [self hideSensitiveData];
                [self getAuthenticatedUserWithModal];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

How does the user know whether or not they are authenticated? **Apple suggests putting your networking code in your models**. If your user object is responsible for dispatching and responding to requests, you can set the authenticated property whenever you receive a callback.

Comment: The issue is really that if a request comes back as failed for a security issue, we want to reauthenticate and then resubmit the request.  Its not just that we only show certain VCs / data to authenticated users.  In that case there is no responsible VC, its a background queue thats sending queued requests to a server.

Comment: If you have an expired token, then it's just a case of whether or not you can get a new one behind the scenes without user intervention. Just pause the background queue that's sending requests to the server and see if you can get a new token. If it works then you can give every request in the queue the new token, if it fails then you should be able to purge the queue and ask the user to reauthenticate.